# How can I set authorization header in Angular filemanager

Tags: angularjs, angular-file-upload

I am using [angular-filemanager](https://github.com/joni2back/angular-filemanager) in my project.

Is it possible to set the authorization header? I use a bearer token and the server needs the following header: "Authorization" "Bearer [token]"

I want to use token to prevent open file manager before login(use file manger address)

Comment: It seems that an [open issue](https://github.com/joni2back/angular-filemanager/issues/326) already exists in angular-filemanager.

Comment: @lzagkaretos, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

In `apihandler.js` file, I add this:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
```